# Pandas Python como cambiar multiples valores

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Buen día
He estado intentando cambiar distintos valores de una columna de un dataframe por uno solo, esto para poder homologar las distintas maneras de escritura de un valor y poder trabajar la información

```
# df.loc[df['Columna1'] == [['USD' and 'Dolar']], "Columna1"] = 'DOLAR'
```

Lo intente hacer con el ".loc" pero solamente me cambia un valor y no todos los valores que establezco, alguien me podría ayudar?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debes ocupar replace, quedaría así:

```
    df['Columna1'] = df['Columna1'].replace(['USD', 'Dolar'], 'DOLAR')
```

me cuentas como te va.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias